# What is the voltage angle?

Tags: voltage, transmission-line

I am trying to learn the basics of electricity. I came multiple times across the notion of a "**voltage angle**" of a node.

For example, when sending \$f_{vw}\$ units of electricity on a line connecting nodes \$v\$ and \$w\$, the following constraint must be satisfied:

$$f_{vw} + B_{vw} \alpha_{w} - B_{vw} \alpha_{v} = 0$$ where \$\alpha_{v}\$ and \$B_{vw}\$ are the voltage angle at node \$v\$ and susceptance of line \$vw\$, respectively.

Could someone please intuitively explain what the voltage angle is and what that constraint encodes?

Comment: It would make sense in a context of phasors. Not exactly the "basics".

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I am also willing to learn what is outside the basics! I am new to the electrical engineering field :D

Comment: Do you have any background in physics, math, or other engineering disciplines? Have you studied trigonometry?

Comment: You appear to be quoting some text.  Could you _cite_ this text, either with a traditional book citation if it is one, or a link to a site if it's on the web.  Also, if possible please _excerpt_ the relevant text to go around the equations you're quoting.  It looks like you've taken away too much of the context for the math to be very meaningful.

Comment: [This](http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/AC/index.html) might be useful as an introduction to "phase angle."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EE, if we have a steady-state sinusoidal signal (voltage or current, typically) with a time dependence
$$ v(t) = V_0\cos(\omega t + \phi)$$

we often represent this as a *phasor*, which is a complex number of the form
$$ \tilde{v} = V_0 e^{j\phi}$$
where \$j\$ is the EE's notation for the unit imaginary number (often called \$i\$ in other disciplines).

This phasor can equivalently be written as
$$ \tilde{v} = V_0(\cos\phi + j\sin\phi),$$
which is just a straightforward application of Euler's identity.

Use of phasors allows us to greatly simplify the solution of many problems when we are dealing with single-frequency steady-state sinusoidal signals applied to linear circuits.

When someone talks about the "angle" of a voltage, they are talking about the phase (\$\phi\$) in these formulas.